# How to display data from 4 tables?

Tags: mysql, opencart

Im trying to get data to display using mysql from across 4 tables (i think) but ive listed all 4 tables below aswell as the columns.

```
table1 = order_product  
Columns = order_product_id, order_id, product_id, name, price, total, tax, quantity  
table2 = product_to_category  
Columns - product_id, category_id  
table3 = category_description  
Columns - category_id, name  
table4 = category  
Columns - category_id, parent_id
```

Im trying to display the (column)-name from table 3 along with
    the total (column)-quantity of items sold & the (column)-total amount in each category from table 1 & in each of the following 4 categories.
    The main category is category_id=177 but
    this has 3 sub-categories being, category_id=191,192,193
    all 3 are linked to the main category using the parent_category=177 in table 4?
    I hope ive explained this much better & provided enough details & thx for any help

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are slicker ways to put this, but I think this query will work for you.

```
SELECT t3.name, t2.category_id, sum(t1.quantity), sum(t1.total)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.category_id = t3.category_id
WHERE t2.category_id = 177 
OR t2.category_id IN (SELECT t4.parent_id FROM table4 t4 WHERE t4.category_id = 177)
GROUP BY t3.name, t2.category_id
```

Comment: thankyou for your help but this only shows 1 row & what I am after showing is 4 x rows.
The top row showing the name of the main category(id=177) being category_description=(name) along with the grand totals (quantity & total) of category_id=191+192+193 then the next 3 lines showing the category_desciption=(name) of 191,192 & 193 as well as the totals (quantity & total) of each category_id=191, 192 & 193 which are linked to the main category_id=177 using parent_id=177 in the category table